# Resource id cannot be an empty string (at 'text' with value '?') in textAppearance attribute

Tags: android, textview

I have the following two textViews in my layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView_playSourceWord"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView_playTheme"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/word_box_margin"
    android:text="Maison" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView_playTargetWord"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView_playSourceWord"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/word_box_margin"
    android:text="?" />
```

I don't have any error for the first one, but in the second one `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"` is generating the following error:

```
error: Error: Resource id cannot be an empty string (at 'text' with value '?').
```

I also have other TextViews in other layouts with the same value for textAppearance and there are no errors there. Is there a way to fix this without having to re-create the style manually?

Comment: Didn't work, sorry. I get these errors: `Multiple annotations found at this line: - error: Error: Resource id cannot be an empty string (at 'text' with value '?'). - error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'textAppearance' with value '\?android:attr/`. Also, my problem is not in android:text, it's in android:textAppearance.

Comment: have you tried @ instead of ? for textAppearance

Comment: I tried "\?" for android:text and the comment in textAppearance did go away... so strange. Why would it mark the error in textAppearance if the problem is in android:text ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to escape ? as coded below

```
android:text="\?"
```

Comment: I tried "\?" for android:text and the comment in textAppearance did go away... so strange. Why would it mark the error in textAppearance if the problem is in android:text ?

Comment: I don't know the actual problem behind this. But these types of issue can be handled simply by clean/build project.

Answer (score 3):

Always use localized strings:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView_playTargetWord"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView_playSourceWord"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/word_box_margin"
    android:text="@string/what" />
```

strings.xml

```
<string name="what">\?</string>
```

Comment: I'm aware of that. This string is just a placeholder so I can test the layout. The actual text will be added dynamically. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I think that was a bug of Android Studio.
Check this path: your project folder/app/build,you will find 3 folders there:"generated","intermediates" and "outputs".All you need to do is deleting all the contents in these folders and rebuild your project.